# Rails fixtures — Incrementing an ID attribute automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, fixtures

I have a fixtures file with ID's like this:

```
post_one:
  id: 1
  attr2: 'some_value'

post_two:
  id: 2
  attr3: 'some_other_value'
```

and so on.

Is there a way I could not have to type in the id's for each record, and have it be incremented automatically?

Comment: You probably want to look at using something like FactoryGirl (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) to generate your test data.

Comment: FactoryGirl is much more flexible, but have you tried just omitting the `id` fields?  Are your ID fields auto incrementing numbers?

Comment: @NickVeys I have not. That is a great idea :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify an id, it will hash the label and use that as the id.  Some benefits of not specifying an id:

- Stable, autogenerated IDs
- Label references for associations (belongs_to, has_one, has_many)
- HABTM associations as inline lists
- Autofilled timestamp columns
- Fixture label interpolation
- Support for YAML defaults

See this page in the documentation for more info on fixtures: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

Comment: from 4.2, only the first three are actually benefits. `There are some more advanced features available even if the id is specified` list the bottom three. See api link provided in answer